# Multiple array operations

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, vector

For my project I need to take a vector array from a file then need to compare it with two A and B vectors and need to find to which one of A and B is closer to the vector we read from file.

**I already did the C++ part (taking values of X from file etc.)**

*For example*: for **X(1,3,5)** , **A(2,4,6)** (**for A distance to X is (|2-1|+|4-3|+|6-5|)= 3**) then i need to do the same operation for the B and find which value is smaller(which means closer to the X vector)

**Basically for 3 sized arrays i need to find difference between X's and A's 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements** *(then need the absolute value of their sum then I need to do this for B then compare two values )*

but I'm really stuck with the Assembly part:

so far i know to find **distance** i need to use this code to find **absolute value** but before using this code down below i need to find the difference between two elements then apply this code to find the absolute value

Here is the code piece for finding absolute value I don't know if that helps:

```
mov ebx, eax     ; move eax to ebx
neg eax          ; eax = -eax
cmovl eax, ebx   ; if negative move ebx back to eax
```

but my **main problem** is: **How can I take the first elements from both X and A  get the difference between their elements in Assembly.**(Need to do this for **2th** and **3th** values of both arrays as well. Then i need to do same operations for X and B but if you show me for A im sure i can apply the same algorithm for B

my C++ prototype of Assembly function is this :

```
distance(int n, int * Xptr, int * Aptr, int * Bptr);
```

and defined A and B as array with 3 members.

Comment: What exactly is causing you problem? Can you access array items?

Comment: @Jester sorry  I tried to explain briefly this time. Basicly i need to acess array items then find the difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access an array using indirect addressing.

Like so:

```
;ecx = number of items in the array
push ebx
push esi
push edi
xor ebx,ebx        ;outcome is zero.
mov esi,Array1     ;esi = address of array1
mov edi,Array2     ;edi = address of array2
add esi,ecx        ;esi = end of array
add edi,ecx        ;edi = end of array
neg ecx            ;start at the beginning of each array
jz done            ;count is zero, nothing to do
loop:              ;for (i=0;i<count;i++)
  mov edx,[edi+ecx]  ;edx = Array1[i] or Array1[start+length-count]
  mov eax,[esi+ecx]  ;ebx = Array2[i]
  sub eax,edx        ;calculate difference
  cdq                ;edx = eax < 0? -1:0
  add eax, edx
  xor eax, edx       ;eax = abs(eax)
  add ebx,eax        
  inc ecx            ;i++
jnz loop
done:
mov eax,ebx
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
ret
```

Let me walk you though the code.
We start with setting the sum to zero and setting pointers to the array.
Then we negate the count and update the pointers to the end of the array.
This seemingly complicated setup is a speed hack, it allows you to count from -count to zero whilst not having to keep an extra variable around to keep track of the array indexes.
Then we do some magic to do an abs without having to do jumps or conditional moves.

You call this routine twice. Once to get `abs(A[]-X[])` and again to get `abs(B[]-X[])`.

For the abs trick, see: https://www.strchr.com/optimized_abs_function

You'll have to do some changes to adjust it to your calling convention. I leave this as an exercise for the reader.  You might adjust the code to do all of the comparisons in one go, which I also leave up to the reader.

just for fun let's pick apart the abs sample:

```
  Alt-A          cycles bytes      Alt B       cycles    bytes 

  mov ebx, eax     0     2         cdq         1          1 
  neg eax          1     2         add eax,edx 1          2
  cmovl eax, ebx   2     3         xor eax,edx 1          2
```

As you can see there is very little difference between the two samples. I just prefer the cdq variant because it's more elegant.

Comment: Thnx but one of the points i have trouble with in this code that Array1 and Array2 is undefined. How can i define them in this code ?

Comment: Pass them as parameters and adjust the `mov esi,Array1` to have esi consume that parameter instead.

Comment: I did it but still doesnt work also this time it gives invalid instruction operands error at lines with `push`.

Comment: I've tested the code, it works, you'll have to do your own translation. SO only allows one question per item. This is actually a new question. If you keep getting stuck, ask a new question: `How do i get this piece of code to compile/run under c++ (version x.xx) using calling convention Y under linux/windows/bsd/... using x86/X64 assembly?`

Comment: Got it. Appericate the code and the explanation. :) Chosen as answer

Comment: And if you're running under x64 you'll need to use the 64-bit versions of push/pop. You'll also need to conform to the calling convention (stdcall on x64 and cdecl on x86).